# Is there an easy way to open PowerShell in admin mode for the current folder on Windows 11?

Tags: powershell, windows-11

## Background

After upgrading to Windows 11, I've encountered an issue where I cannot open PowerShell in administrator mode directly from toolbar.
This method is mentioned here: [How to run PowerShell with admin privileges from the current folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40599282/how-to-run-powershell-with-admin-privileges-from-current-folder)

## Workaround

I found a workaround that typing `powershell` in the file explorer's address bar, which opens PowerShell in the current folder but not with administrator privileges.

## Seeking Solutions

However, I'm specifically looking for a solution or an alternative method to open PowerShell with administrative rights directly from the toolbar or anywhere else conveniently.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this in Windows 11?

Comment: Looks like you're not the only one missing this feature. Found a suggestion 
 [here](https://medium.com/@mozzeph/launch-windows-terminal-as-admin-from-windows-11-context-menu-8eb2abe7b28b).